# While using internet on ubuntu, all other computers get bad internet connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, broadcom, router

I am currently using Ubuntu 10.04 Precise (in dual boot with Windows 7).

Whenever I log onto Ubuntu Internet, all other computers Internet speeds plummet.  Usually we have 20 Mbps download and 2 upload.  However, when I log onto Ubuntu I can still get this on this computer but all other computers go to about .5 Mbps download and .6 Mbps upload.

When I log into Windows on the same machine the Internet works fine on all other computers.

My ISP is currently Time Warner. The router is SBG6580 [Motorla](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0040IUI46)

here is my wireless card:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at fb200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78 <?>
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-3d-ff-ff-70-e4-d5
    Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting <?>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma, brcmsmac
```

output of `ifconfig` for wireless:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e4:d5:3d:70:81:b3  
          inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e6d5:3dff:fe70:81b3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36476 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:9891
          TX packets:29153 errors:8 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:43805291 (43.8 MB)  TX bytes:6741638 (6.7 MB)
          Interrupt:16
```

Any advice or debugging assistance would be **greatly** appreciated!!!
Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us:
- are all clients using wireless to connect? Or are others wired connections?
-do you have ipv6 enabled on any of the clients?
-what kind of encyption is used by the clients? Are they all using the same or is it mixed? I have experienced this kind of problem with one client using TKIP while the other is on AES
-do you have the latest firmware on the router?

Comment: Hi matv1, thanks for the comment, All clients which start to slow down are using wireless, I have an xbox connected directly which doesn't appear to be affected.  I am use DHCP on all wireless and the encryption is WPA and WPA2 Personal. My router page does say: `WPA/WPA2 Encryption: TKIP+AES.`  I am not sure if I have the latest firmware but here is what it says: `Standard Specification Compliant DOCSIS 3.0
Hardware Version 2
Software Version SBG6580-3.5.8.2-GA-00-488-NOSH`
Thanks again for your help

Comment: Update - I tried changing the router to only AES, still have problems with internet connection on other computers.

Comment: OK another update. I typed dmesg after I had a short internet blip(which also happens frequently) and I saw some logging which I'm not sure if shows any problems or not but here it is:
http://pastebin.com/Bvc9duvG
Thanks again!

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I was going on the assumption that Ubuntu wireless was working well, just that it was impacting throughput on your other connections. Now I understand that the connection on your ubuntu is dropped sometimes as well.
What I notice in your dmesgis that the wifi client doesnt know which regulatory domain it is in. I know that when this is not set, it can create problems for the connection as well as on the router side. To solve this, you should set your domain (assuming your in the US) in the terminal like this:
-sudo apt-get install iw-
then do:
-sudo iw reg set US-

Comment: I was having the same problem; using the solution on the answer below semmed to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

From @Matv1 comment:

> I'm a bit confused. I was going on the assumption that Ubuntu wireless
>   was working well, just that it was impacting throughput on your other
>   connections. Now I understand that the connection on your ubuntu is
>   dropped sometimes as well.
>   What I notice in your `dmesgis` that
>   the wifi client doesn't know which regulatory domain it is in. I know
>   that when this is not set, it can create problems for the connection
>   as well as on the router side.
>
> To solve this, you should set your domain (assuming your in the US) in
>   the terminal like this:
>
> sudo apt-get install iw
>
> sudo iw reg set US

Comment: i am having the same problem, i am from INDIA how can i fix this?

Comment: Seemed to solve the problem I was having. Thanks!

Comment: im facing the same problem with the same wifi-card device and this is not solving it :/ it doesnt even just decrease the others pc´s wifi, it literally kills it. But i have super fast internet. this sucks so hard