# Nobody can use the internet when I turn on my computer?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, router

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS along with an old Windows installation. Every time I boot with Ubuntu. Nobody can use the internet if the wireless is on. Windows works fine though.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more details or accurate diagnostic please ?

Comment: Also give us some details about your network topology.

Comment: When you say "Nobody", are you talking about other computers, or just people using your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: I have found the solution.I just had to search for the right question. => [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254383/while-using-internet-on-ubuntu-all-other-computers-get-bad-internet-connection). Btw, 'Nobody' was reffering to other computers connected to the same router I use. Thank you for your help I appreciate it.