# BCM4313 eats up all the wifi

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I have a problem similar to this : [While using internet on ubuntu, all other computers get bad internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254383/while-using-internet-on-ubuntu-all-other-computers-get-bad-internet-connection)

So the problem is, whenever I log onto Ubuntu Internet, all other computers Internet speeds goes down drastically. We have 20 Mbps download and 2 upload. However, when I log onto Ubuntu I can still get this on this computer but all other computers go to about .2 Mbps upload.

When I log into Windows on the same machine the Internet works fine on all other computers.
I tried the fix mentioned in that post i.e. I tried "*sudo iw reg set US*" in vain.

OS: `13.04`
Network Card:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: c0:cb:38:0f:b4:50
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=204.140.128.251 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:17 memory:fbd00000-fbd03fff
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:4d:a2:94:2a:8a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c0:cb:38:0f:b4:50  
          inet addr:204.140.128.251  Bcast:204.140.131.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c2cb:38ff:fe0f:b450/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6229 errors:1 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:15408
          TX packets:5608 errors:11 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5849916 (5.8 MB)  TX bytes:1117895 (1.1 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:118319 (118.3 KB)  TX bytes:118319 (118.3 KB)
```

dmesg output is pasted here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5987128/ .
One thing I have noticed is after I do the *iw reg set US* it appends the following to dmesg output:

```
[  805.955556] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[  805.963964] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[  805.963973] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  805.963980] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[  805.963987] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[  805.963993] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  805.963999] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  805.964005] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  805.964010] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
```

which is automatically removed after every reboot.
Any advice or debugging assistance will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!

Comment: If you disable the wireless card, do the problem go away? Try unloading the wl module and loading brcmsmac instead: `sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe brcmsmac`

Comment: This is also a posible bug with the restricted drivers according to [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/1097519/comments/12) in the Launchpad bug report: *Interference with other devices on local WLANs*

Comment: @Braiam Thanks for pointing me to the bug report. I observed the interference problem but I ignored it thinking its too weird. The loading/unloading of the wl module helped but the internet speed on other devices is still half of what my ubuntu laptop is getting! Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So the solution to the problem if it aint solved by:

```
sudo apt-get install iw
sudo iw reg set US
```

is to unload the 'wl' kernel module and load the brcmsmac like Braiam said:

```
sudo modprobe -r wl && sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Thanks Braiam